# Extract specific segment from m3u8 playlist using

Tags: python, c++, http-live-streaming, m3u8, transport-stream

I wish to extract parts from an m3u8 hls playlist given 'start time' and 'end unix time'

Assuming,

> start unix time = 1667112116900

> end unix time = 1667112133040

Example input file =

```
#EXTINF:5.9610000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112094442.ts
#EXTINF:5.3340000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112100495.ts
#EXTINF:5.2380000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112106453.ts
#EXTINF:5.4280000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112111854.ts
#EXTINF:5.3340000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112116984.ts
#EXTINF:5.3330000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112122404.ts
#EXTINF:6.6370000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112127907.ts
#EXTINF:6.2000000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112133401.ts
#EXTINF:6.2000000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112139827.ts
```

Required output file =

```
#EXTINF:5.3340000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112116984.ts
#EXTINF:5.3330000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112122404.ts
#EXTINF:6.6370000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112127907.ts
#EXTINF:6.2000000000,
/home/aanisnoor/Videos/DVR/segments_test_push/1667112133401.ts
```

There are more than 4000 lines from which I need to extract.
Apologies for no code included as it was very incomplete.
Python/C++ would work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the complete playlist but if you have one or more [EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis#section-4.4.4.6) tag in your playlist then you can easily relate the start of each segment to a wall clock time. Then you could convert that to a Unix time and easily make the comparison.

The implied time of each segment is the sum of the PROGRAM-DATE-TIME, plus all the durations from the EXTINF preceeding the segment in question.

In Python, it would probably be easiest to do this with a library like [m3u8](https://github.com/globocom/m3u8).